# How to test conditional styling made with Material UI makeStyles()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I've been working on a React app for a few weeks and I use Material UI components for most of by base.

I have this component that has its style change depending on the values of its props. To do this, I did something like:

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles({
    component: {
      ...
      backgroundColor: getComponentBackgroundColor(),
      ...
    }
  });
```

with `getComponentBackgroundColor()` being defined as

```
  const getComponentBackgroundColor = () => {
    if (props.someProp) {
      return "green";
    }
    return "red";
  };
```

and then by setting the component's `className`.

My problem is that I want to test this component to ensure that the styling is correctly applied (some `getStyle()` methods are more complex than juste looking if a prop exists or not).

I'm using the `react-testing-library` and my first instinct was to check if the rendered component had the right `className`, but upon further inspection, I realized that `makeStyle()` assigns some random className like `makeStyles-component-12` to each component. I also noticed that components with the same styling had different classNames. So that was a no-go.

Is there an easy way to test conditional styling when using Material UI's `makeStyles()` ?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's not recommended to couple your tests with specific class or css style, you could use [jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavestyle)'s `.toHaveStyle` matcher to test if the right style is applied when passing the corresponding props.